# Неожиданное поведение валидации при сохранении

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель со следующими валидациями:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true

  validates :password,
            length: {in: 6..72},
            confirmation: true

  has_secure_password validations: false
end
```

При сохранения инстанса этой модели (`save!`) срабатывает валидация :length у :password. Самое интересное то, что пароль при этом не изменялся. В частности, такое поведение возникает, например, тогда, когда я обновил поле `email_confirmed`.

```
@user.email_confirmed = true
@user.save! # заметьте, что пароль никак не изменялся, он уже существует в БД в виде хеша, и он однозначно не меньше 6 символов
```

Да и вообще во всех случаях, когда вызывается метод `save` или `save!`. Пробовал добавить на валидацию модификатор `on: :create`, но мне такое решение не подходит, так как при смене пароля (update) новый пароль не валидируется.

Также пытался установить только `on: [:create, :update]`, но при таком подходе все равно выбрасывается исключение, вызванное валидацией.

Предположил, что стоит вместо вызова `save!` использоваться метод `update(param: value)`, но я не считаю это самым рациональным решением, тем более, что решение использовать `save!` было внесено не мной, а куда более опытным разработчиком.

Также прошу заметить, что с валидацией email все в порядке, ни один вызов `save!` не жалуется на то, что email'а нет.

Собственно, в чем может быть дело? Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено (хотя оно довольно не очевидно, но тем не менее):
нужно добавить валидацию `allow_nil: true`